# Django Heroku deployment - ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: django, git, heroku

There are a few posts with this particular issue however I've tried about five or six different suggestions from those posts and have had no luck.

When trying

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\DjangoBlog\src> git push heroku master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to murmuring-dusk-96030.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-dusk-96030.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-dusk-96030.git'
```

From the build log on the Heroku website:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I have a simple static website running Django 2.2.3 as back end. I've been developing in a virtual environment on my local machine and have the following project structure shown blow, where `src/` was what I renamed the folder created by the django-admin startproject command.

[image: File directory structure]

I'd like to deploy my site on Heroku so I've signed up, installed Git and the Heroku CLI. In my terminal I've logged in to Heroku and initialized my Git repository in this top level root (`src/`). I've added a `Procfile` which contains the following:

```
web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -
```

I have the following in my `runtime.txt` file. I'm actually running 3.7.3 in my virtual environment but I've tried both ways:

```
python-3.6.1
```

To settings I added:

```
import django_heroku

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # added this:
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

My `requirements.txt` contains all packages I'm using and `psycopg2`, `whitenoise` and `gunicorn`, `django-heroku`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can see what the buildpack is looking for here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `requirements.txt`, along with your [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location) and [`runtime.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime), [must be in the top-level root directory of your project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#the-basics).

Move them there, commit that change, and deploy again, e.g.

```
cd $PROJECT_ROOT
git mv src/requirements.txt .
git mv src/Procfile .
git mv src/runtime.txt .
git commit -m 'Move requirements.txt and Heroku files to root'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: src is my root directory and the one in which I ran the git init command. Procfile, runtime.txt and requirements.txt are within this directory src.

Comment: So your project's `.git/` directory is also in `src/`? You see `src/.git/`? Editors often show what's in the top-level, version controlled, project root directory in their file explorers. This suggests that your `.git/` is actually one directory above `.src/`.

Comment: You're right - I just checked in windows explorer with hidden files view on, I see my .git folder is up a level than I thought it was. I'll try move everything out of src to where .git is and restage and commit. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That fixed it! Massive noob mistake on my part but at least now I know. Won't make that mistake again.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, @Blargian. This is quite a common mistake. I made it myself when I first started with Heroku.